# Returning parts of lines in a text file in C

Tags: c, regex, string, validation, text

I have a text file with usernames and passwords laid out like this:

```
Username        999999
```

I'm trying to extract the lines in order to put the usernames into an array and the passwords (which are on the same line) into a separate array. I'm new to C and cant figure out how to do this.

As i'm trying to validate user authentication, I feel another way this could be done would be with regular expressions. e.g. user inputs a username, the lines in the text file are matched to find the line with this input. User inputs a password, the same line is validated to see if the password matches the username.

Does anyone know how I could implement this?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just too vague and open-ended.

Comment: Just read the line with, for example, `fgets` and use `sscanf(buf, "%s %i", vet, &num)`. With fgets save line just read in a string called buf, the second part of sscanf is called parsing, then vet and num are variables where you can save the string and the number.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if the entry in the file is in the format of key: value pair. Then you can use XML, or JSON parsing libraries to get the desired result.

Comment: Are there really quotes around each line?

Comment: No quotes around each line, edited post

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple exaple --

> > -- open the file "data" containing lines of the type `username  number`
> >
> > -- loop over the file reading such lines one by one
> >
> > -- for each line initialize the variable `name` with the username and the variable `N` with the number
> >
> > -- print username and N and loop again until the end of the file is reached.

Suppose the username is shorter than 100 chars, otherwise it will segfault.  Also, suppose the number is less than usinged long, otherwise it will be truncated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  FILE *f = fopen("data", "r");
  char name[100];
  unsigned long n;
  while (fscanf(f, "%s %u", name, &n)!=EOF) 
  {
    printf("%s -- %u\n", name, n);
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would've made this better